# Acumatica Odata Generic Inquiry not found

Tags: odata, acumatica

When I try a PUT to access the Acumatica Odata link (already logged in)

```
https://www.myaccumatica.com/MyCompany/odata/JSM Sync INTran?$format=json&$top=10
```

The data sent with the PUT is an empty set {}.

The PUT returns the following error

```
"odata.error": {
  "code": "",
  "message": {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "value": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://www.myaccumatica.com/MyCompany/odata/JSM Sync INTran?$format=json&$top=10'."
  },
  "innererror": {
    "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset'.",
    "type": "",
    "stacktrace": ""
  }
}
```

The Generic Inquiry is in the Site Map as required.

[image]

The error is odata.error, so I figure the Acumatica Odata feature is processing my request, but I can't figure out why it does not see the Generic Inquiry.

Comment: Did you enable "Expose via OData" ? I can't see it from your screenshot.

Comment: @Rick yes. Image updated.

Comment: Did you try to GET instead of PUT ?

Comment: @Rick yes, but it errors before getting to the Acumatica odata logic. A PUT at least gets to the odata logic inside Acumatica, returning the odata.error as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the spaces from the URI.

See the Acumatica help [page](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=339f2b58-c593-456a-8bad-a8eb7b7db8d8):

> If the display name contains invalid symbols, these symbols are removed from the name. For example, Account Name is converted to AccountName.